# How do you go about picking a belt in design?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, dynamics, power-transmission, mechanical-failure

So when you want to pick a beam to use or determining the thickness of a load bearing beam, or picking bearings, there is some calculations you do to see if its life expectancy or f.s or to see if the deflection are within your design constraints.

How do you go about doing the same thing for a belt, I have a nitro engine with 3.6hp output, and when I went to find a mathematical way of calculating belt width/thickness and whatnot there seems like there isn't much other than calculating wrap angle or this ratio which gives the tension/compression factor.

So lets say you have 3.6hp you need to transmit with a belt, you want it to be a timing belt, and as light of a system as possible, what math do you do?

*side note it says the question is subjective, but I'm merely just ask for a method to verify a belt in design, other than experience”

Comment: size the belt according to the power that will be applied to it - belt manufacturers have listings...

Comment: right, but speed also plays a role in that? other than just following manufacturer recommendations how do you go about doing it? for example my application is 20k rpm plus and 0.9hp per belt. Its been done before with a mxl style timing belt, but im pretty sure it was far out of spec, because it doesnt include rating for that high rpm low power range

Comment: Perhaps they phoned the belt company and got something made…

Comment: Contacting the supplier is the best way to specify anything 'standard' like belts - you may not have experience, but they absolutely do, and they will ask you the questions that they need to know.